# Strong NP-completeness of permuted kernel problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

The permuted kernel problem is NP-complete problem by simple reduction from partition problem. In fact, it is strongly NP-complete by reduction from 3-partition. The literature points to Garey and Johnson for the reduction from 3-partition. I checked G&J but did not find the reduction. Do you have a reference that contains the reduction?

Permuted kernel problem

Given a matrix A and vector X, Is there a permutation $P$ of vector X such that $A*X_P=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_1,\dots,S_{3m}$ denote the integers that form the 3-partition instance.  Let $T=(S_1+\dots + S_n)/m$, so that $T$ is the target sum for each triple.  As noted on Wikipedia, without loss of generality [we may assume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem#Variants) that $S_i \in (T/4,T/2)$ for every $i$.

Let

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1 &0&0&0 &\cdots &0&0&0 &1 &0 &\cdots &0\\
0&0&0 &1&1&1 &\cdots &0&0&0 &0 &1 &\cdots &0\\
 & &  & & &  &\ddots & & &  &  &  &\ddots &\\
0&0&0 &0&0&0 &\cdots &1&1&1 &0 &0 &\cdots &1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where there are $m$ rows and $4m$ columns.  Let

$$X = (S_1,\dots,S_{3m},-T,-T,\cdots,-T).$$

Then $A,X$ is an instance of the permuted kernel problem, and it has a solution iff the original 3-partition instance has a solution.

Comment: What is vector X?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany, see if you can figure it out.  What do you think would be a natural choice?

Comment: Assuming all elements in X are non-zero, I don’t see how to get A*X=0 ( I assume n is the number of elements in 3-partition instance.)

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany, you are right.  Sorry.  See edited answer.